# JW Player 7.4.2 not working on HTML5 for HLS at chrome version 50.0.2661.102

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer7

Am using jwplayer 7.4.2 enterprise version, Looking forward to use the html5 provider for HLS, Made all configuration changes, but still not working in html5 mode at chrome. But working fine in Edge. Do i need to make any other change?

Seeing the Following error in Chrome.

[image]

Comment: what's the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 7.4.2 player, as of yet, does not render HLS in HTML5 in Chrome by default.

If you are using a self-hosted player, you can add `hlshtml: true` to your embed code.

If you are using a cloud-hosted player, there will be a setting in the player configuration in the Account Dashboard soon that will allow you to enable this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If your jwplayer is hosted on a different domain than the HLS stream (which is usually the case), you will need an appropriate Access-Control-Allow-Origin HTTP header coming from the server with the HLS stream.